# using paste0 in file name in exams2moodle

Tags: paste, r-exams

I am trying to create a loop to automatize exams generation using the `exams`package....

I have created a series of exercices like this

```
gr1 <- c("ae1_IntroEst_1.Rmd","ae1_IntroEst_2.Rmd","ae1_IntroEst_3.Rmd","ae1_IntroEst_4.Rmd")

gr2 <- c("ae1_IntroProcEst_1.Rmd","ae1_IntroProcEst_2.Rmd","ae1_IntroProcEst_3.Rmd","ae1_IntroProcEst_4.Rmd")

...etc...
```

Now, I am creating a loop to export all the exercices to moodle xml:

```
for (i in 1:2){
  grupo <- paste0("gr",i)
  exams2moodle(grupo, name = paste0("mt1_",i, "_M"), dir = "nops_moodle", encoding = "UTF-8", schoice = list(answernumbering = "none", eval = ee))
}
```

But I am getting this error:

`Error in xexams(file, n = n, nsamp = nsamp, driver = list(sweave = list(quiet = quiet,  :  The following files cannot be found: gr11.`

If I replace "grupo" by "gr1" then it works... (but I am generating 20 exercices). I can't figure it out...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: A workaround is to create a list, say
grM <- list(gr1, gr2) and then use exams2moodle(grM[i]),....
but I am still puzzled why the paste0 does not work,..

Comment: The list solution is what I typically use for the purpose you describe. I prefer that to the get() solution that @uzsolt describes nicely in his answer (+1).

Comment: Does the solution by uzsolt answer your question? If so, please accept it so that it is flagged correspondingly here on SO. If not, please refine the question so that we can fully resolve it.

Comment: Yes, it does, but as you say, I also think the list solution works better for my purpose. I do thank uzsolt for his solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `grupo` is a string: `"gr1"`. The `exams2moodle`'s first parameter is a string (in your case) and not the list of files (as you want).

If you want use a variable which name is in a string variable, you should use [get](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/get) (*get: Return the Value of a Named Object*)

Check the sample code:

```
> x <- 'foo'
> foo <- 'bar'
> x
[1] "foo"
> get(x)
[1] "bar"
>
```

In your case:

```
for (i in 1:2){
  grupo <- paste0("gr",i)
  exams2moodle(get(grupo), name = paste0("mt1_",i, "_M"), dir = "nops_moodle", encoding = "UTF-8", schoice = list(answernumbering = "none", eval = ee))
}
```